# htaccess redirect rule help please (wildcard in URL)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm rebuilding a site from the ground up, but the site I'll be replacing already ranks pretty well for SEO.

I have a number of pages in the format of the following:

```
http://URL/SECTION/ANOTHERSECTION/send-me-information-on-PRODUCTNAME.php
```

"send-me-information-on-" is consistent across all products.

I can write redirects on a per product basis, but I've got more than 200 products so it would be great to handle this using a rewrite rule.

What I need to achieve is the following New URL:

```
http://URL/SECTION/ANOTHERSECTION/product-information-request.php?product=PRODUCTNAME
```

Now I understand for SEO purposes, this probably isn't the best approach, but I'd like to maintain a single information request page.

I figured the best approach would be to use a Regex to match the string, and set an environment variable which I'd use in the resulting URL. I'm not too familiar with .htaccess rules though.

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/send-me-information-on-([^.]+).php$ $1/$2/product-information-request.php?product=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: this didn't seem to work with the trailing / after the first ^ however this could just be my explanation above. Either way, it's working now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: yes you're right, I never know if you need the / at the beginning.